# display messes up size of div

Tags: css, flexbox

This is before `display: inline-flex;` is implemented:

[image: image here]

code:

```
.testing {
    float: right;
    }
```

This is after `display: inline-flex;` is implemented:

[image: image here]

code:

```
.testing {
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
    }
```

Comment: @MrLister Okay so `display:inline-block;` doesn't change the size, but it does change the float, how can I still control the float?

Comment: @MrLister the comparaison won't work here because of the float ... float will always force display to be block whatever display you use (inline, inline-block, block) so such changes shouldn't happen ... there is probably something else involved

Comment: can you share a more complete code so we can better identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Float** removes the element from the normal flow and makes it a "block" element. If `display: flex;` or `display:  inline-flex;` is used with float, then float has no effect on that particular element. In your case the "inline-flex" changes the size of the div to fit on that particular row where it is "in-lined";

If you want your element to be the same size and is aligned right you should make use of [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), more specifically use `display: flex;` on parent and `justify-self: end;` on child. See more here: [Justify-self: end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self)